# What is the best way to take pictures of a document on an LCD screen?

Tags: lcd, moire

Getting records from the courthouse. They charge $1/page to print which is utterly insane but will let you discreetly take pictures of the computer screen instead.

I have my iPhone and the pictures are usually readable but there are always lines or rgb dots that show up. Is there a technique or anything you’d recommend to take better pictures?

And yes, I’ve already looked into uploading documents from the computer itself. The computer is on a network whitelist. It can access the court website and nothing else. Also it’s run on a vm on top of a basic windows pc. So it’s not an option to have a flash drive.

Here’s an example of a picture I’ve taken.

[image]

Comment: Be very, very, *very* careful taking photos of anything in a court setting unless you've cleared it with your lawyer first that it's OK.

Answer (score 2):

The effect is called [moire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern).
You can easily avoid it by taking deliberately defocused photos.

Start by framing a slightly bigger picture and holding your finger on the screen until **AF/AE LOCK** appears:
[image]

Taking a photo at this moment would give us the well known unwanted pattern, so don't do it:
[image]

Instead, move the phone a few inches closer for the final framing and shoot:
[image]
Moire is no more! :-)